# PHP unlink Delay

Tags: php

I'm having some issue with the `unlink` function.

I have a page that when refreshed, it searches a directory for newly added files. The user may choose to manage the files and can also delete any file. However, when the user deletes the file, there is almost a 5 second delay before the actual file is deleted from the server directory. In the meantime, if the user refreshes the browser, that same file that was supposed to be deleted re-appears as a new file. The issue with this is that if the user deletes this file again, the file no longer exists because of that initial delay...

Any thoughts on this? It's driving me crazy and not sure how to remedy this situation...

Comment: Could it be that it really is deleted, but the browser gets a version of the directory from a cache?

Comment: Not really 'cause I physically watch the file get deleted from the folder and takes almost 5 seconds before it disappears...

Comment: `clearstatcache();` documentation is here http://php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php

Comment: I'm not convinced `clearstatcache()` will help. `unlink()` does not appear in the list of affected functions, and there is this explicit note: _unlink() clears the cache automatically._

Comment: Dimitri, is there a chance this is a server configuration issue? Are you using RAID or any sort of buffering that would step between PHP and the filesystem?

Comment: If you're using ajax, the browser cache could also be involved. What adding the `expires` etc. headers to your php to try ?

Comment: [This comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php#101637) on the documentation may help you

Comment: The way I have it set up is that there is an Ajax call triggered by the user which is the handled by an internal function within a class from the remote file that does other Ajax stuff. The thing is, it always works and doesn't fail, it's just that delay that always occurs. I tried clearstatchache() but I've had no luck with it...no buffering involved or server config changes. I've never had a problem in the past.

Comment: @so geek  I read that comment... So basically I would have to inform the user the file has been deleted once the process is over? What if another user logs into the page and recreates the problem? I'm not sure if there's a true solution because the user gets informed than the file is deleted while in reality, it's not. I wish there was a "pause" or "lock" before the user gets informed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be to create a new file when you call unlink(), and name the new file $original_filename."_deleted". Then when you list the files, exclude any ending with "_deleted".  Then you just need to worry about cleaning up all the "_deleted" files every so often with a cron job.

```
    function my_unlink($filename){
      touch($filename.'_deleted');
      unlink($filename);
    }

    function list_files(){
      if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
        while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
            if ($entry != "." && $entry != ".." && !preg_match('/_deleted$/',$entry)) {
                echo "$entry\n";
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Interesting approach, I'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

`clearstatchache(true, $file)` still might be worth a try, though I am pessimistic after the documentation on `unlink`.

Maybe there are too many files in the directory, and using several directories might help (using directories with the first two chars of the file name).

My hope however goes that the listing overview page is cached. Using

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
```

or so might help.

Comment: I'll give this a try and see. There are around 100 PDF files in the folder and all less than 4 mb in size. Whenever a new file comes in, a function reads the folder and adds the name of the file in the DB once the page is accessed.

Comment: 100 files should not slow down directory scanning. (You do not have a backup/mirroring running I presume.)

Comment: That's what I was thinking also, 100 files is not a lot, perhaps the file is too big and takes longer. Even at that, the process needs to finish completely before informing the user. Maybe throw in a delay somewhere?

Comment: You could also throw some hardware at the problem, like using an Solid State Drive instead of a Hard Drive should help you.

Comment: Yea, I'll probably end up modifying some hardware. I was considering replacing the hard drive for an SSD.